# How to populate Map<string, string> using input values

Tags: javascript, angular

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsthen?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I have the following model

```
export class Items {
  items: Map<string, string>;
  createdBy: string;
  deliveredBy: string;
}
```

I want to dynamically create input fields based on items in an array which I am able to I am unable to figure out how to populate data in those fields.

```
<form>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let item of myStringArray">
            Map {{item}}<input name="value" ([ngModel])="data.items.set(item)" (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
    </td>
        <td>
            Always Present One <input ([ngModel])="data.createdBy" (ngModelChange)="onChange()" />
    </td>
        <td>
            Always Present Two<input ([ngModel])="data.deliveredBy" (ngModelChange)="onChange()" />
    </td>
    </tr>
</form>

{{ data.items | json }}
```

Components.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  public myStringArray = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
  data = new Items();

  onChange() {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

I found a reference but I am unsure where I am going wrong

[Reference Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqr9bb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: you need to define keys first as mentioned in "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqr9bb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html", then get it and set it's value

Comment: @abhi9393, `public myStringArray = ["First", "Second", "Third"];` are the keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your Stackblitz:

- You cannot directly bind to a `Map` within an `ngModel`. You need to `get` in the `ngModel` and `set` in the `ngModelChange`:

  ```
  <td *ngFor="let item of myStringArray">
    Map {{item}}<input name="value" [ngModel]="data.items.get(item)" 
  (ngModelChange)="data.items.set(item, $event)">
  </td>
  ```
- The syntax for the two way binding is "banana in a box" `[(...)]` not the opposite:

  ```
  Always Present One <input [(ngModel)]="data.createdBy" />
  ```
- Are per the console error "If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions." you need to either set `ngModelOptions` or add a name field:

  ```
  Always Present One <input [(ngModel)]="data.createdBy" name="createdBy" (ngModelChange)="onChange()" />
  ```

Here is a new [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cstbum?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. I understand the point of having a form control. But in case where I am dynamically creating the input, how can I make sure that I pass ONLY the typed input value to the console and NOT the array. Is there a way I can just send the value? Or do I need to use array manipulations for that?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I'm getting what you mean? Anyway, i would recommend you to use reactive forms and especially the FormArray for what you are trying to achieve. it's maybe more complex than simple models but way more powerful.

Comment: Nevermind, I was about to delete the comment because I was just not thinking correctly. What I wanted was ; if I type "abc" to the dynamic input field , I should get that to the console. (I understand how to now so no explanation required). 
Thank you for helping me figure this out.

Comment: ok glad you solved it! But I must say using a Map has its challenges, and I rarely use them. Also since Angular 6 you have the `| keyvalue` pipe that lets you iterate over a regular object like `{ "item1": "value1", ... }` like this: `<td *ngFor="let item of data.items  | keyvalue">` which is super helpful and can easily replace a Map.